# How can I search an xml file with perl for a specific character string?

Tags: xml, perl

```
$characterString = $verb[2];
$inputFile = $targetdirectory."/ppt/slides/slide".$slidenumber.".xml";

open FILE, "<$inputFile>";
  for (@lines) {
  if ($_ =~ /$characterString/) {
    print "Matched $characterString \n ";
  } else {
    print "Did not match $characterString\n";
}
}
close FILE;
```

Here is a sample from the XML file:

```
<a:t>Bailey</a:t></a:r></a:p><a:p><a:pPr lvl="1"><a:lnSpc><a:spcPct val="90000"/>
```

Here is the output:

```
PUB ENGINE: Version 5-26-2015
Did not match billybob
Did not match Bailey
```

Bailey is in the xml file, but billybob is not

Comment: Here is a sample from the xml file

Comment: <a:t>Bailey</a:t></a:r></a:p><a:p><a:pPr lvl="1"><a:lnSpc><a:spcPct val="90000"/>

Comment: What is `verb`?  Where do the strings `billybob` and `Bailey` come from?  What does your command line look like for your example?

Answer (score 3):

The first two major issues:

1. You are trying to open a file whose name ends with `.xml>`.

   ```
   open FILE, "<$inputFile>";
   ```

   should be

   ```
   open FILE, "<$inputFile";
   ```

   Well, not really. It should be

   ```
   open(my $FILE, '<', $inputFile)
      or die("Can't open \"$inputFile\": $!\n");
   ```

   This avoids the use of global vars, this avoids the file name from being treated as anything but a file name, and this checks if the `open` succeeded (being a common point of failure).
2. You never read from the file handle.

   ```
   for (@lines) {
   ```

   should be

   ```
   while (<FILE>) {
   ```

   Or if you adopted my suggested change,

   ```
   while (<$FILE>) {
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you're taking the wrong approach. XML doesn't parse well with line and regex based parsing - there's a variety of ways to create semantically identical XML that doesn't match the same regular expressions.

I've had to adjust your XML a little too, because it's not valid. I am assuming that because you mention 'sample' that your XML *is* valid. For reference - it's useful to provide sample XML that's valid - which means all the tags open/close.

So I'm using this:

```
<root>
  <a:r>
    <a:p>
      <a:t>Bailey</a:t>
    </a:p>
  </a:r>
  <a:p>
    <a:pPr lvl="1">
      <a:lnSpc>
        <a:spcPct val="90000" />
      </a:lnSpc>
    </a:pPr>
  </a:p>
</root>
```

Note this can be written in a variety of ways:

```
<root
><a:r
><a:p
><a:t
>Bailey</a:t></a:p></a:r><a:p
><a:pPr
lvl="1"
><a:lnSpc
><a:spcPct
val="90000"
/></a:lnSpc></a:pPr></a:p></root>
```

Or:

```
<root><a:r><a:p><a:t>Bailey</a:t></a:p></a:r><a:p><a:pPr lvl="1"><a:lnSpc><a:spcPct val="90000"/></a:lnSpc></a:pPr></a:p></root>
```

All of which mean the same - and hopefully illustrates why using line based parsing is a bad idea. This may not entirely apply to your use case, but I'm a firm believer that using an XML parser whenever XML is involved is no bad thing.

Anyway - finding elements.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $search = 'Bailey';

my $found;
XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => {
        '_all_' => sub { $found++ if $_->text =~ m/$search/ }
    }
)->parsefile($inputFile); 

if ($found) {
    print "Found $search\n";
}
else {
    print "Didn't find $search\n";
}
```

Note - only 'finds' the keywords in the text of the XML, rather than in any of the attributes. This is usually more desirable than just blind matching XML structure/attributes/content.